# How to read integers between white spaces?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Hangman game project in which the user can have 15 guesses and 4 spaces to check. The numbers (of spaces) are separated by spaces. Here is my code, but it doesn't work for some reasons. Any help is appreciated !

```
System.out.println("\nPlease enter the letter you want to guess: ");
        char guessLetter = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (Character.isLetter(guessLetter)){
            System.out.println("Please enter the spaces you want to check (separated by spaces): ");
            String guessSpaces = input.next();


            for (int index = 0; guessSpaces.charAt(index) == ' ';index++){
                if(guessSpaces.charAt(index)== secretWord.indexOf(guessLetter)){
                    System.out.println("You guess is in the word");
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't copy the program properly (there are no closing braces).

Comment: yeah! I only copied the part that I have question on. I didn't want anyone to think I need help with the entire code lol

Comment: Your for loop doesn't make any sense to me.  Can you explain what you think the for loop is doing?

Comment: Yeah your for loop looks like the problem. Index from 0 to a character equal to a space increase index? You need to set how many times the loop should run and then do any comparison stuff inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code, but if you want to read some integers, this is how to do it:

```
String[] strings = input.nextLine().split(" ");
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : strings) {
    if (s.trim().equals("")) {
        continue;
    }
    integers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

Now you have a list of integers stored in `integers`. For example, if I enter

```
90 68 6 786
```

The array list will contain exactly that. However, if you enter some invalid values in there, an exception will be thrown.

Also, it seems like that your for loop is checking whether the letter that the user entered is in the secret word. No need to use a for loop for this! Just do this:

```
if (secretWord.contains(Character.toString(guessLetter))) {
    System.out.println("Your guess is in the word!");
}
```